# Circumference of the curve

Tags: calculus, curves

We have a cardioid curve. The length of the curve is given form the relation $\int_a^b |z'(t)|dt$.

How can we find the circumference of the cardioid curve???

Comment: What is the exact equation of your curve? If you have the parametric equation, you can use the formula you have to solve it.

Comment: I have the parametric equation $$z(t)=(1+\cos t)(\sin t-i \cos t), 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$$ Which formula do you mean??? The formual of the length of the curve??? @KittyL

Comment: What do you mean by circumference then? Isn't it the length of the curve?

Comment: But why do they use two different words for that??? 

$$z'(t)=-\sin t (\sin t -i \cos t)+(1+\cos t )(\cos t+i \sin t)$$ Correct??? @KittyL

Comment: Just to confuse you. :P Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Is the integral $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \sqrt{(\cos 2t+\cos t)^2+(\sin t+2 \cos t \sin t)^2}dt$$ ??? @KittyL

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @KittyL And how can we calculate this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sqrt{(\cos 2t+\cos t)^2+(\sin t+2 \cos t \sin t)^2}\\=\sqrt{(\cos 2t+\cos t)^2+(\sin t+\sin{2t})^2}\\
=\sqrt{\cos^2{2t}+\cos^2{t}+2\cos{2t}\cos{t}+\sin^2{2t}+\sin^2{t}+2\sin{t}\sin{2t}}\\
=\sqrt{2+2(\cos{2t}\cos{t}+\sin{t}\sin{2t})}\\
=\sqrt{2+2\cos{(2t-t)}}\\=\sqrt{2+2(2\cos^2{(t/2)}-1)}=2|\cos{(t/2)}|$$

This can be integrated easily.

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} 2 |cos(t/2)|dt=\int_0^{\pi} 2 \cos{(t/2)}dt-\int_{\pi}^{2 \pi} 2 \cos{(t/2)}dt\\
=4\sin{(t/2)}|^{\pi}_0-4\sin{(t/2)}|^{2\pi}_{\pi}$$

Can you go from here?

Comment: So is the circumference equal to $4( \sin{\pi} - \sin 0)=0$ ???

Comment: With circumference do you mean the perimeter???
How do we find this??
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} 2 |cos(t/2)|dt$$

Comment: @user159870: I edited the answer.